# Setting up Google Apps with Rackspace

Tags: google-apps

Posted questions on Google help, but no response.

Simple question: I know I need to delete existing MX records and create the new ones with their corresponding priorities in order to set up Google Apps. Question: Do I need to mess with A/CNAME at all? Like do I need point any of my domains (mail.mydomain.com, pop.mydomain.com) to a new IP? Or do I really just delete the MX records and add the new ones?

The google basic instructions don't say anything about having to do this, but I wasn't sure...

Answer (score 0):

Just setting up MX records is enough to receive emails.

You will need CNAME/A only to access access you Gmail interface via mail.yourdomain.com - which isn't that much of an improvement since it redirects to mail.google.com anyway.

You will need to prove you're owner of the domain when registering Google Apps suite, and adding a special CNAME record is a way to do it, but you can also upload a special html file provided by setup wizard.